# Neat extraction of elements in nested lists (Mathematica)

Tags: list, nested, wolfram-mathematica, extract

This is a question about rearranging parts of nested lists in Mathematica.
I've got a nested List:
`DatenList = {{1, {100, 200}}, {2, {101, 201}}, {3, {102, 202}}};`
and want to get another list like
`{{1,100},{2,101}}`

Is there a neater way than
`temp = DatenList[[1 ;; 2, 1]];
temp2 = DatenList[[1 ;; 2, 2]][[;; , 1]];
temp = {temp}~Join~{temp2};
finalList = Transpose[temp]`
which yields
`{{1, 100}, {2, 101}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
temp2 = DatenList[[1 ;; 2, 2]][[;; , 1]]
```

can be written shorter as

```
temp2 = DatenList[[1 ;; 2, 2, 1]]
```

Otherwise, the whole operation can be done several ways :-

```
finalList = {#1, First[#2]} & @@@ DatenList[[1 ;; 2]]

finalList = DatenList[[1 ;; 2]] /. {a_Integer, {b_, _}} :> {a, b}

finalList = Replace[DatenList[[1 ;; 2]], {a_, {b_, _}} :> {a, b}, 1]

finalList = MapThread[{#1, First[#2]} &, Transpose[DatenList[[1 ;; 2]]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I like the first solution best.